# Object is invalid PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I use a dataset that has billing information:

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KUq8.png)

And I want to create a procedure that gives information about a specific bill by giving an invoice id

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_information(
    invoiceID varchar(11);
) IS
    p_smtable supermarket%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO p_smtable FROM SUPERMARKET
    WHERE invoice_id = invoiceID;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_smtable.brancj || p_smtable.city);
END;
```

The compilation is successful.
[Compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foMxL.png)

```
begin 
print_information('750-67-8428');
end;
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Error starting at line : 12 in command -
begin 
print_information('750-67-8428');
end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.PRINT_INFORMATION is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What does "show errors procedure print_information" return?

Comment: Why are you creating your objects in the SYSTEM schema??

Comment: This is a project task. And I am asked to create a new database. I couldn't, so I use the system.

Comment: I already tried it @Suresh

Comment: "Build an Oracle database that holds your chosen dataset"  You may be right @Suresh

Answer (score 1):

The code in the screenshot is different to the version in your question, but both have an error at line 2. The parameter should be `varchar2` or `supermarket.invoice_id%type`, with no semicolon.

Also, we normally use a `p_` prefix for parameters, not variables. (There are other conventions, but whatever you use, `p_` for a variable is just confusing.)

A fixed version might be:

```
create or replace procedure print_information
    ( p_invoice_id supermarket.invoice_id%type )
as
    l_market supermarket%rowtype;
begin
    select * into l_market
    from   supermarket
    where  invoice_id = p_invoice_id;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_market.brancj || ' '|| l_market.city);
end;
```

Whatever tool you are using for development, you need to become familiar with how to display compilation errors.

`brancj` might be a typo for `branch`.

I've assumed you want a space between branch and city, otherwise the output would be something like `TottenhamLondon` rather than `Tottenham London`.

In Oracle a schema belongs to one user, created with the [CREATE USER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html) command. An Oracle Database is the entire thing (all users, all data, storage, memory, processes, everything) so you would not normally create one for something like this.